# Downloading data from the datastore

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

I wanted to download the data on my online app's datastore, I followed [the guide on code.google](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Setting_Up_remote_api), I added this to my `app.yaml` file

```
builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

But when I updated using `appcfg.py update src` and called this:

```
appcfg.py download_data --application=myapp --url=http://myapp.appspot.com/remote_api_path --filename=first-test-backup`
```

I got an Authentication error, pretty much the same case [mentioned here](https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/d1a96f6066b216c2/71a16461a4a86c88), so I tried putting this:

```
- url: /remote_api 
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py 
  login: admin
```

before any catch-all handlers, but then got this error: `threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler` when I tried to update, so according to [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/aa96ce1fd1d2f757), I replaced it by:

```
    - url: /remote_api 
  script: google.appengine.ext.remote_api.handler.application 
  login: admin
```

Which gave me again the authentication error, I also tried adding `('/remote_api', google.appengine.ext.remote_api.handler)` to  `app = webapp2.WSGIApplication`, however still the authentication error persists.

I use a High Replication datastore, but according to [code.google](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Setting_Up_remote_api) the only drawback is that I might not get the latest data.

How can I download my data?

Comment: I am using python 2.7, it's still experimental though: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

And for url

```
appcfg.py download_data --application=~myapp --url=http://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=first-test-backup
```

Atttention `_ah` in url: `http://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api`

Comment: Thanks, not just that I had to add the `_ah`, I also had to remove the `_path`.. how silly of me :)
but still I needed to do one last change to the value of  `--application` which is adding a `s~` so it would be: `s~myapp`

Comment: I downloaded it successfully now.. any idea how to view it? can't view it with a text editor..